# Help menu on new meta toolbar has CSS issues

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, top-bar, firefox

In the new top bar on Meta, when we hover over the options under the `help` menu, it'll show an extended selection view.

[image: Extended Selection]

Additional Info:

Browser: Firefox 23
OS: Windows 7

Comment: What browser and OS are you using? It works correctly for me in Chrome 31 on Mac OS X.

Comment: Reproduced on Firefox 25.0 Windows 7

Comment: Right, tagged with Firefox then until someone can reproduce it with more browsers.

Comment: No repro on internet explorer 10 on windows 7

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Added browser info to the question

Comment: Reproduced on Nightly 26.0, Windows 7

Comment: Looks like this has been fixed at some point.